# Spring Boot OAuth2 - authenticate with Facebook using local user database

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am creating website using Spring Boot, Spring MVC and spring-security-oauth2 and I am trying to authenticate my locally stored users against Google, Facebook, GitHub ... OAuth2 services. I also have standard username-password for them.

My idea is to store pair of [OAuth2_provider_type,OAuth2_subjectId] for each user to local database from the first success oauth login and then use this pair to find correct user when user authenticate himself by Google (or FB...) again. I have correctly authenticate with Google/Facebook but I don't know how to connect my local stored users to Spring OAuth2 Security and get them to SecurityContext.

Could somebody point me to some example or integration test where I can see something similar?

Here I found great tutorial [Spring Boot and OAuth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) with hints in section *How to Add a Local User Database* . Tried to redirect from Google to *Authorized redirect URI* `http://localhost:10001/user` endpoint which is defined like `.antMatchers("/user").authenticated()` and get *Access Denied*

`o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /user?state=Wj7RVk&code=4/wa2AFtJr0K3cKTxDAYo8rTOu2p41km5o3YCPnimx4wU; Attributes: [authenticated]
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6fa8940c: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 5888363FA9E329992073DCE4B21E8B5C; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@29802df4, returned: -1
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied`

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

> Tried to redirect from Google to Authorized redirect URI
>   http://localhost:10001/user
>
> o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object:
>   FilterInvocation: URL:
>   /user?state=Wj7RVk&code=4/wa2AFtJr0K3cKTxDAYo8rTOu2p41km5o3YCPnimx4wU;
>   Attributes: [authenticated]

Looks like you are doing it in a wrong way, you shouldn't go to `/user` with the `code` and `state` params! The flow is:

1. You register an sso endpoint for an url like
   `localhost:8080/login/facebook`
2. Once you clicked to a link which leads to the endpoint you get
   redirected to facebook authorization page
3. Once authorized you should be redirected back to
   `localhost:8080/login/facebook` with your state and code params:
   `localhost:8080/login/facebook?state=Wj7RVk&code=4/wa2AFtJr0K3cKTxDAYo8rTOu2p41km5o3YCPnimx4wU`
4. When sso filter gets the code is goes to the facebook again to
   exchange access_code to access_token and puts the token into session
5. In the end of the process `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` is called to redirect
   you according to its concrete imlementation (usually it is
   `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`)

If these steps were completed successfully you can go to `/user` endpoint to get some user information.